# MySQL - Iterating over columns in a result set

Tags: java, mysql, loops, resultset

I'm working on a project where a user can assemble the components of a yoga class.  It's spread across several files and thus too large to put it all here.  The trouble I'm having is in one method where I need to iterate over the horizontal columns of a result set that is returning only ONE ROW from a MySQL database.

I understand that I have to position the cursor on the first row of the result set (which I believe I am doing). Since I have only one row in the result set (my variable is rset), I should be using rset.next() only one time, correct?  And then I should be able to use a simple loop to iterate over each column and append the value to my String Builder.  I want to skip the first column and append each subsequent value until the loop reaches columns with null values.  I cannot find why my code keeps returning a "Before start of result set" exception.

Can anyone spot anything wrong?

I'll post the method as well as the method called by this method. (I posted this in a different question, but I believe the nature of my question has changed, so I'm re-posting this with a different title.)

```
    // Query that returns the poses within a specific section
public String listPosesInSection(String tableName, String sectionName) {
    String strList;
    StringBuilder strBuilderList  = new StringBuilder("");
    // Run the query
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        // Query will collect all columns from one specific row
        rset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + "_name = '" + sectionName + "'");
        rset.next();  
        System.out.println("Column count is " + countColumnsInTable(tableName));
        for (int i = 2; i <= countColumnsInTable(tableName); i++) {// First value (0) is always null, skip first column (1)
            System.out.println("test");
            strBuilderList.append(rset.getString(i) + "\n"); // This is line 126 as indicated in the exception message
            }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    strList = strBuilderList.toString();
    return strList.replaceAll(", $",""); // Strips off the trailing comma
}

// Method for getting the number of columns in a table using metadata
public int countColumnsInTable(String sectionType) {
    int count = 16;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + sectionType);
        rsMetaData = rset.getMetaData();
        count = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return count;
}
```

And here is the first part of the exception message:

```
Column count is 26
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:855)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5773)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5693)
at YogaDatabaseAccess.listPosesInSection(YogaDatabaseAccess.java:126)
at YogaSectionDesigner$5.actionPerformed(YogaSectionDesigner.java:231)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you're re-using the `rset` between your two methods. So when  `countColumnsInTable` has completed, the `rset` variable is pointing to a different result set than it was before, in `listPosesInSection`. And that result set has not been advanced with `next`, hence the error message you're getting. You probably want to assign it to a local `ResultSet` within that method instead.

```
public int countColumnsInTable(String sectionType) {
    int count = 16;
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + sectionType);
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rset.getMetaData();
        count = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Remember to clean up
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 public String listPosesInSection(String tableName, String sectionName) {
        String strList;
        StringBuilder strBuilderList  = new StringBuilder("");
        // Run the query
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            // Query will collect all columns from one specific row
            rset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + "_name = '" + sectionName + "'");
            while (rset.next()){
            System.out.println("Column count is " + countColumnsInTable(tableName));
            for (int i = 2; i <= countColumnsInTable(tableName); i++) {// First value (0) is always null, skip first column (1)
                System.out.println("test");
                strBuilderList.append(rset.getString(i) + "\n"); 
                }
             }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        strList = strBuilderList.toString();
        return strList.replaceAll(", $",""); // Strips off the trailing comma
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

rset is a ResultSet object

i think you are using the same ResultSet object in listPosesInSection and also in countColumnsInTable

so what is happening here is in listPosesInSection rset holds a result and you have also move the cursor but again in countColumnsInTable you are using the same rset so it is overwritten ie it holds a new result now, you are getting the number of columns but since it holds a new result now the cursor will be before the 1st record so use different Resultset object in countColumnsInTable

Comment: Thank you!  You folks are great!